# C# binary writing return bigger file

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, binarywriter

im having a little trouble with a binary writer issue, my program is set to load SHIFT-JIS characters, and write in the same encoding, but it returns a file bigger in size :s although i remove several Characters, [here is a sample of the files before and after writing](http://www.mediafire.com/?9tuaoafr79smj5l), these are the open and save codes:

```
private void Openbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        textBox1.Text = "";
        menuItem12.Text = "file type is: ";
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Open File";
        ofd.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            menuItem13.Enabled = true;
            menuItem14.Enabled = true;
            menuItem15.Enabled = true;
            path = ofd.FileName;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path), Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT-JIS"));
            foreach (char mychar in br.ReadChars(4)) menuItem12.Text += mychar;
            if (menuItem12.Text != "file type is: TXTD")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This is not a TXTD file...", "Sorry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                    MessageBox.Show("File opened Succesfully!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    br.BaseStream.Position = 0x8;
                    int Pntrnum = br.ReadInt16();
                    menuItem11.Visible = true;
                    menuItem11.Text = Pntrnum.ToString();
                    List<int> offsets = new List<int>();
                    br.BaseStream.Position = 0x10;
                    for (int i = 0; i < Pntrnum; i++)
                    {
                        offsets.Add(br.ReadInt32());
                    }
                    Dictionary<int, string> values = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < offsets.Count; i++)
                    {
                        int currentOffset = offsets[i];

                        int nextOffset = (i + 1) < offsets.Count ? offsets[i + 1] : (int)br.BaseStream.Length;

                        int stringLength = (nextOffset - currentOffset - 1);

                        br.BaseStream.Position = currentOffset;

                        var chars = br.ReadChars(stringLength);
                        values.Add(currentOffset, new String(chars));
                    }

                    foreach (int offset in offsets)
                    {
                        listView1.Items.Add(offset.ToString("X")).SubItems.Add(values[offset]);
                    }

                    br.Close();
                    br = null;
            }
        }
        ofd.Dispose();
        ofd = null;
    }
private void Savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(path));

        int number_pointers = Convert.ToInt32(menuItem11.Text);

        Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT-JIS");

        bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x10;
        int curr_pointer = 16 + number_pointers * 4;

        //pointers writing
        for (int i = 0; i < number_pointers; i++)
        {
            bw.Write(curr_pointer);
            curr_pointer += enc.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text) + '\0';
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < number_pointers; i++)
        {
            bw.Write(enc.GetBytes(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + '\0'));
        }

        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        bw = null;
    }
```

i truly appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the open function could possibly do to a file size, if thats changing it, then that function is doing something horribly wrong.. otherwise is menuItem1 always the same?

Comment: menuitem1 is openbtn, i only renamed it so u guys can say which is which, also, i thought maybe im doing something wrong in the open function, and that is like reading the jap characters as UTF or something, the sample files are under your service sir.

Comment: I'd recommend you copy your save function into a console application and change the `.text` values to example valid item sthat they could be, I don't like clicking on links to files, sorry. EDIT: I have also done a lot of work with Shift-JIS and I'm sure you know it is a nightmare of an encryption to work with, if possible, I would just use UTF-8 anyway as its supported a hell of a lot more

Comment: i understand the concern but im not one of those butthurt internet users who spreads virus across the net, im really serious and i've been trying to fix this problem for over 4 days now :/

Comment: well ignoring the file sizing, does the actual shown text look the same after saving and loading?

Comment: it looks the same, since it's loaded from pointers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking inside the "After" file in the Samples.zip you provided seems to indicate that you're outputting the same string twice, or something...

I would suggest you start with smaller files to test on, and to use the debugger to step in.

Actually, having tried that myself, i think i found out what's going on: you're using "nextOffset - currentOffset" as a stringLength, but it's actually a BYTE-Length... The char array will end (have a '\0' inside it) after only half this number, and when outputting you'll also get the second half, that you haven't yet read.

[Edit]
Posting the code from my comment below, for better formatting:

```
int index;
for (index = 0; index < stringLength; ++index) if (chars[index] == '\0') break;
if (index < stringLength) {
    char[] relevantPart = new char[index];
    Array.Copy(chars, relevantPart, index);
    chars = relevantPart;
}
```

Comment: is there anyway i could set the length to where it meets a 0x00 ?

Comment: Of course, but then you'll need a new array to hold only the relevant characters... Something like:

    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < stringLength; ++index) if (chars[index] == '\0') break;
    if (index < stringLength) {
        char[] relevantPart = new char[index];
        Array.Copy(chars, relevantPart, 0, index);
        chars = relevantPart;
    }

Comment: thank you, but it still gives me an error: **No overload method 'copy' takes 4 arguments** on the `Array.Copy` line :/

Comment: Oops, i didn't test this part of the code (that's why i said "Something like")... Use **Array.Copy(chars, relevantPart, index);** instead (as shown in the answer). This time i tested it. :D

Comment: thank you, well the debug launch was successful, trying to open the file and [this](http://gyazo.com/a781d0251e2f136d00079c73273e4447.png?1366556409) happens, NullReferenceException, i think it's the file that has the problem, but i am not sure.

Comment: "charQs"?! You have a typo... Also, my code was meant to be used **BETWEEN** "var chars = br.ReadChars(stringLength);" and "values.Add(currentOffset, new String(chars));", not instead of...

Comment: no actually i had to create an array, so i created Chars array, but since there is a Chars "class" or "branch" in VS, i renamed it to Charqs :/, just saw your edit, didn't change anything sadly

Comment: there is no "chars", only "Char" and "char"... Your original variable, "var chars = br.ReadChars(stringLength);" was just fine.

Comment: alright now working good, there is a little pointer problem, but i think i'll manage to fix it, thank you sir, and i apologize for any annoyance i may have created